# is this cupertinobottomsheet available in flutter without using any package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get the same top corner views as in ios.For better understanding I attach screenshoot of this view. [image]
is there any way of doing it without using a package?

I tried each solution in stackoverflow but none of them helped.I used  showCupertinoDialog, showCupertinoModalPopup,showCupertinoModalSheet ,but none of them gives the same view.

```
showCupertinoModalSheet(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              CupertinoPopupSurface(
                                                  child: Container(
                                            width: size.width,
                                            height: size.height * 0.9,
                                          )),
                                        );
```

Comment: Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet flutter has not provided it yet by default.

Comment: Thank you  @Muddassar  I used this package.However I thought flutter has provided but i have not known.